# Unable to determine XPATH with nested SVG elements

Tags: selenium, xpath

On front it showing in a tabular form with four columns and i wanted to click on second column where something written. I confirmed  and  tag has not been used. when i am trying to locate that element giving me '0 element' selected when i am trying with different way of writing xpath.

In chropath when tried with '
`//div[@class='slick-viewport']/div/div'` - it showing me 21 elements as a result are below:

```
<div class="ui-content slick-row odd" style="" xpath="1"></div>
<div class="ui-content slick-row even" style="" xpath="2"></div>
<div class="ui-content slick-row odd" style="" xpath="3"></div>
<div class="ui-content slick-row even" style="" xpath="4"></div>
<div class="ui-content slick-row odd" style="" xpath="5"></div>
<div class="ui-content slick-row even" style="" xpath="6"></div>
```

......and so on
 When i am expanding one of result (out of 21) which has four  tag and my requirement is click on 2nd div tag which appear as 2nd column in front.

```
<div class="ui-widget-content slick-row odd" style="" xpath="1">
    <div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l0 r0" style=""></div>
    <div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l1 r1" style=""></div>
    <div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l2 r2" style=""></div>
    <div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l3 r3" style=""></div>
</div>
```

And when i am expanding above all  tag it the code is as below.

```
<div class="ui-widget-content slick-row odd" style="" xpath="1">

<div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l0 r0" style="">
     <a href="javascript:void(0) " style="font-size: 10pt; text-decoration: 
     none; color: #026fbe; line-height: 29px;" onclick="Manager.Details"></a>
</div>

<div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l1 r1" style="">
     <svg width="100%" height="25" version="1.1" id="SVG_e1b7a2e4-0548-469c- 
     898d-9f723cea80ef" data-managerid="471" 
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     onclick="openSummary('SVG_e1b7a2e4-0548-898d-9f723cea80ef')" style="">
  <g>
     <defs></defs>
     <rect width="100%" height="25" style="stroke-width:1;stroke: #B3B3B3" 
     fill="url(#e1b7a2e4-0548-469c-898d-9f723cea80ef)"></rect>
  </g>
  <text x="10" y="17" fill="black" style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: 
  12px;" id="PopUp_e1b7a2e4-0548-469c-898d-9f723cea80ef"></text>
  <g></g>
</svg>
</div>

<div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l2 r2" style="">
       good
</div>

<div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l3 r3" style="">
       better
</div>
```

When tried with following code in chropath it showing '0' element:

```
 //div[@class='slick-viewport']/div/div/div/div[2]//*[name()='svg' and id='SVG_c9f91db7-1452-4038-ab06-39e']//*[name='g']//*[name()='rect']
```

but id of svg is getting change every time so i tried with following but same result. i.e '0' element.

```
//div[@class='slick-viewport']/div/div/div/div[2]//*[name()='svg' ]//*[name='g']//*[name()='rect']
```

Even tried with following but same result i.e 0 element.

```
//div[@class='slick-viewport']/div/div/div/div[2]//*[name()='svg']//*[name() ='g']//*[name='rect' and @fill='url(#9fff3df4-9671-4514-ade8-29da06c46c96']
```

Please any one knows how to write xpath using svg, please help me out.

Comment: Can you please check if  data-managerid is static if so then try to use this for identifying your element?

Comment: yes its static let me try, and will let you know. thanks.

Comment: //div[@class='slick-viewport']/div/div/div/div[2]//*[name()='svg' and data-managerid='498']//*[name='g']//*[name()='rect'] same result. '0' element.

Comment: Tried following as well but didn't work.                                                 //div[@class='slick-viewport']/div/div//*[name='svg' and  @data-measureid='498']//*[name='g']//*[name()='rect' and @fill='url(#9fff3df4-9671-4514-ade8-29da06c46c96']

Comment: check below solution

Answer (score 0):

if you want to identify react element as per your DOM and data-managerid is static and unique then please go with below xpath

`"//*[name()='svg']//*[name() ='g']//*[name()='react"]`

Comment: For code //div[@class='slick-viewport']/div/div//div[1]/div[1]//div[2]/svg//rect, same result '0 element matching'.

Comment: Pleas share your site if possible

Comment: Sorry as per company security policy i can not.

Comment: Check above one please

Comment: Same result - '0 element matching'

Comment: Check if its under iframe or not

Comment: No, it is not and if its in frame then it should not show me the result 21 elements with code  //div[@class='slick-viewport']/div/div  right!, am i right? or still  need to be checked/confirmed about iframe? I checked once.

Comment: Also check step by step new updated solution to identify problem like 1. check  //*[name()='svg'] 2. //*[name()='svg']//*[name() ='g'] 3. //*[name()='svg']//*[name() ='g']//*[name()='react'] at least will get to know where is the problem

Comment: WIth this too //*[name()='svg']//*[name() ='g']//*[name()='react'], 0 element matching, i think need to be try with data-managerid, that is unique.

Comment: WIth this too //*[name()='svg']//*[name() ='g'] are you getting something

Comment: '0 element matching  getting, oh sorry getting 69 elements with  //*[name()='svg']//*[name() ='g']

Comment: with svg only getting 39 elements

Comment: And when expanding each, its mostly related to style i guess.                                    svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="settings-icon" id="settings-icon" xpath="1">
<g id="systemsettings" style="">
<path d="M24,14.18V9.82H19.89A8.13,8.13,0,0,0,19.12,8L22,5.06,18.94,2,16,4.88a8.13,8.13,0,0,0-1.85-.77V0H9.82V4.11A8.13,8.13,0,0,0,8,4.88L5.06,2.13,0,0,0-.77,1.85H0v4.36H4.11A8.13,8.13,0,0,0,4.88,16L2,18.94,5.06,22,8,19.12a8.13,8.13,0,0,0,1.85.77V.89A8.13,8.13,0,0,0,16,19.12L94,19.12,16a8.13,8.13,0,0,0,.77-1.85ZM16.36,12A4.36,4.36,0,1,1,2Z"></path>
</g>

Comment: i am trying to fetch svg only as per dom, want to click on 2nd column and the entire row contains 4 columns and 4 div tag for individual column is there. Manually i can click on second column anywhere its about the size of 35% of entire row. And when i click  one window will popup and it gives many different measures.

Comment: 0 element matching